# Ruby File.open strange behaviour

Tags: ruby, file

I found a very strange behaviour of File

```
[3] pry():1> File.zero?(file.path)
=> true
[4] pry():1> file.size
=> 3894
[5] pry():1> File.zero?(file.path)
=> false
```

The real file sizes from `[3]` and `[5]` can be confirmed by checking them in bash.

Is there an explanation for this behaviour? One thing to mention before is that `file.class` might be `File` or `Tempfile` and it happens in both cases.

Comment: It might be helpful to show what happens in `[1]` and `[2]`. Do you write to the file?

Comment: no, i was checking the path

Comment: Any chance it's a network file server issue? NFS used to do some weird stuff back in the day…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this seemingly bizarre behavior is because each `File` object has a [File::Stat object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File/Stat.html) to encapsulate common status information about the file that is only updated when some action is taken that triggers an update. In this case the trigger is you calling `size` on the file. You can examine the `stat` object to see timestamps.

Here is a fully reproducible example with the `stat` call thrown in.

```
irb(main):021:0* f = File.new "out", "w"
  => #<File:out>
irb(main):022:0> f.write "hi"
  => 2
irb(main):023:0> File.zero? f.path
  => true
irb(main):024:0> f.stat
  => #<File::Stat dev=0x801, ino=1062714, mode=0100664, nlink=1, uid=1000, gid=1000, rdev=0x0, size=0, blksize=4096, blocks=0, atime=2015-11-05 15:50:25 -0800, mtime=2015-11-05 15:52:08 -0800, ctime=2015-11-05 15:52:08 -0800>
irb(main):025:0> f.size # triggers an update
  => 2
irb(main):026:0> File.zero? f.path
  => false
irb(main):027:0> f.stat
  => #<File::Stat dev=0x801, ino=1062714, mode=0100664, nlink=1, uid=1000, gid=1000, rdev=0x0, size=2, blksize=4096, blocks=8, atime=2015-11-05 15:52:47 -0800, mtime=2015-11-05 15:52:45 -0800, ctime=2015-11-05 15:52:45 -0800>
```

Although, I would think that calling `write` on a `File` object should trigger an update.

EDIT: I figured out why `write` does not trigger an update. `write` is a method of `File`'s parent class (`IO`). But `size` and `stat` are both methods of `File`. Therefore, the `write` method would have to be implemented in `File` in order to gain access to (or knowledge of) `stat`. I suspect that any call to a method implemented in `File` will update `stat`.